# How to display the Radial type of pattern associated with electric consumers

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, utility-network

I have a point dataset of electrical poles (feature data set under FGDB) and also i have the consumers data in non-spatial format (excel sheet), the excel sheet having a pole ID field which is the common  field with point dataset as well. I have joined the data and generated an output file, which having all the data in it.
example - Pole ID -ABCD/1 showing 5 Consumers joined with it.
Here i want to display the radial type of pattern of consumers connected with the pole only when i click that particular pole (Point). I couldn't find any such solution for in ArcGIS.
Below attached image will illustrate how i want to show the data.
Example data attached...
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

First, have you looked through the [assorted ArcGIS solutions for Electric Utilities](https://www.esri.com/arcgis-blog/products/arcgis-solutions/electric-gas/get-started-with-the-electric-utility-network-an-overview/)?

Second, it sounds like you want to have a bunch of networks, but with limited visibility (only when selected). Could you potentially build a bunch of tiny networks (one per pole), symbolize them to be invisible, and then show this layer over the poles layer, so when you think you're clicking on a pole you are actually clicking on the invisible pole network layer? Here is information on [how to build a network dataset](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/extensions/network-analyst/exercise-1-creating-a-network-dataset.htm).